# stop python script from terminal

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I have an android app and a raspberry pi. I create connections via ssh between them. I send commands from my android app to the rpi and these commands typically run python scripts.

My plan is the following: As long as my phone is in a specified radius regarding to the gps coordinates, I'd like to run python scripts. If I1m out of that radius, I'd like to stop that python script. How can I stop a running python script from terminal/cmd?

Thanks

Comment: Use the `kill` command to kill a process by PID. You may also have a `killall` or `pkill` command that can search for processes by name and kill them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So, for example if I run a py script like "python /home/pi/py/derek.py --name alma", I can send a command in a couple minutes like "kill derek.py" and that's it?

Comment: No, `kill` takes a numeric process ID. This is basic Unix skills, not a programming question.

Comment: This may be a better fit for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) rather than Stackoverflow.

Comment: In order to get the PID to pass to `kill`, have your Python script write it to a file like `/var/run/mytool.pid` on startup (using [`os.getpid()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getpid)).

Comment: Barnard is correct. If you want to harness the potential of your Raspberry Pi you need to familiarize yourself with Unix. Raspian, as far as I know, is a full GNU/Linux operating system.

Comment: Ok, I'm in the middle of unix, but I'm not that deep into it yet. I've already used kill command, but not for py scripts. What's the best and the most secure way? pkill, kill, killall for stopping py script?

Comment: Look this up on SuperUser. If you can't find an answer there, then ask a question there.

Answer (score 3):

You can stop EVERY python script by wunning the command

```
sudo killall python
```

in the terminal. Killing individual scripts will require the PID of the python script you wish to stop.